# Invalid results while performing difference in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame created using csv file. Its a simple task to calculate the current age of the students. I have a field called birthyear. The field has NULL values in between for a few students. I am running the below code:

```
df <- read.csv("students.csv", header = TRUE)
df$age <- (2017-as.numeric(df$birthyear))
```

I am not getting the correct age. Rather I get the same results as the field `df$birthyear`. On running just `as.numeric(df$birthyear)`, I expect to get the year i.e. 1994, 1995, 1988, etc. but rather I am getting the below

For 1994, I am getting 53
For 1980, I am getting 39 and so on.

Unable to understand why I am getting these integer values where I should get the year.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the birth years are being imported as strings and then being automatically converted to factors. When you call `as.numeric` it returns the level codes rather than the labels. Try importing the data with `stringsAsFactors` set to `FALSE`.

```
df <- read.csv("students.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```